# In R, conditionally left join two tables depending on the value of an indicator variable in the left-hand-side table

Tags: r, join, dplyr

**Background**

I've got two dataframes about baseball cards and their market value. This information comes from Baseball Card "Almanacs", guides to cards' value published every year.

The first, `d`, is a table with the `card_id` of each card, as well as an indicator `almanac_flag`, which tells you if the `card_id` in that row came from the either the 1999 or 2009 editions of the Baseball Card Almanac:

```
d <- data.frame(card_id = c("48","2100","F7","2729","F4310","27700"), 
                almanac_flag = c(0,0,1,0,1,0), # 0 = 1999 Almanac, 1 = 2009 almanac 
                stringsAsFactors=T)
```

It looks like this:

[image: d]

The second dataframe is `d2`, which contains (not all) equivalent `id`'s for 1999 and 2009, along with a description of which baseball player is depicted in that card. Note that `d2` doesn't have *all* the ID's that appear in `d` -- it only has 3 "matches" and that's totally fine.

```
d2 <- data.frame(card_id_1999 = c("48","2100","31"),
                card_id_2009 = c("J18","K02","F7"),
                description = c("Wade Boggs","Frank Thomas","Mickey Mantle"),
                stringsAsFactors=T)
```

`d2` looks like this:

[image: d2]

**The Problem**

I want to join these two tables so I get a table that looks like this:

[image: d_esired]

**What I've Tried**

So of course, I could use `left_join` with the key being either `card_id = card_id_1999` or `card_id = card_id_2009`, but that only gets me half of what I need, like so:

```
d_tried <- left_join(d, d2, by = c("card_id" = "card_id_1999"))
```

Which gives me this:

[image: d_tried]

In a sense I'm asking to do 2 joins in one go, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we do the reshape to 'long' format from 'd2', it should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d2 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('card'),
       values_to = 'card_id', names_to = NULL) %>% 
     right_join(d) %>%
     select(names(d), everything())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  card_id almanac_flag description  
  <fct>          <dbl> <fct>        
1 48                 0 Wade Boggs   
2 2100               0 Frank Thomas 
3 F7                 1 Mickey Mantle
4 2729               0 <NA>         
5 F4310              1 <NA>         
6 27700              0 <NA>
```

---

or another option is to `match` separately for each column (or join separately) and then do a `coalesce` such as the first non-NA will be selected

```
d %>% 
   mutate(description = coalesce(d2$description[match(card_id, 
       d2$card_id_1999)], d2$description[match(card_id, d2$card_id_2009)]))
  card_id almanac_flag   description
1      48            0    Wade Boggs
2    2100            0  Frank Thomas
3      F7            1 Mickey Mantle
4    2729            0          <NA>
5   F4310            1          <NA>
6   27700            0          <NA>
```